# SSRS sub-reporting and multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, dataset, subreports

I have a main one page SSRS report which links to 16 individual tabs (when exported to excel).

Tabs 1-8 all use the same dataset, and as they are built individually, when the main dashboard runs, it takes an awful long time running the same dataset 8 times on each subreport... Is there anyway to make the main dashboard run whilst querying it only once? Tables 9-16 use different unique datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use shared dataset for 1 to 8. By using a shared dataset you can provide a query that can be used by more than one report.

You can read more about shared dataset here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633675.aspx

Comment: In fact you should cache the shared dataset.

Comment: Query results for a shared dataset can be copied to a cache to provide consistent data for multiple reports and to improve response time for the dataset query.

See Link below. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx